# Button does not contain a constructor that takes 0 argument

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I am currently working on  a Xamarin PCL project on VS2017. Under Android project, I created a class called TestBtn. The code is as shown below. I followed the button metadata and declared the constructor accordingly as shown below. But I am getting an error of Button does not contain a constructor that takes 0 argument.

Any idea why this I am getting this error?

```
namespace CustomRibbonRenderer.Droid
{
    public class TestBtn: Button
    {
        public TestBtn(Context context)
        {

        }
   }
}
```

Comment: `public TestBtn(Context context,  IAttributeSet attributeSet ) : base( context, attributeSet ){ }` - try this

Comment: Cool it works. Thanks yupi! :D Any idea why the : base( context) is required though?

Comment: It's required to link the .NET representation of `Button` to the Android/Java runtime version of `Button`. This lets the Xamarin.Android runtime instantiate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Button` represents a push-button widget. Push-buttons can be pressed, or clicked, by the user to perform an action. Acording to the Xamarin documentation `Button` class accepts 4 public constructors and one protected:

```
Button(Context)
Button(Context, IAttributeSet)
Button(Context, IAttributeSet, Int32)
Button(Context, IAttributeSet, Int32, Int32)
```

Error was appearing in your code because you didn't call `base()`. `base` keyword is used in constructors. A derived class constructor is required to call the constructor from its base class.

Answer (score 0):

You have one constructor that takes one argument (context). Error might arise if  initializing  TestBtn with no arguments.